# How to change an attribute in JS or jquery? With or without an if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have an input field where someone can or don't have to input an image link.
I want that the html file render a standard image (if someone didn't input an img link).
jQuery/JS should check if src="" in my img tag is empty and change it with my standard image url.
I can't make it to work.

I tried various stuff already, now I try it with jquery:

`#showP` is the Id in my `<img>`

I tried this version:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  if (!$("#showP").attr("src")) {
    $("#showP").attr("src", "https://example.com/standard.png");
  }  
});
```

And this version:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$("#showP[src='']").replaceWith.attr("src","https://example.com/standard.png");
});
```

Both versions doesn't work.

Comment: Your first version should work. Please show the HTML.

Comment: Make sure that showP id should be unique through out the DOM and should not be repeated for any other DOM element

Comment: Doesn't work, this is the rendered html:`<img id="showP" style="max-width: 80%" class="rounded img-fluid" src="">` Yes, the ID is unique.

Comment: Your code works fine: [see codepen](https://codepen.io/barbsan/pen/RwbgyMN?editors=1011) Are you sure that `https://example.com/standard.png` call is successful and you don't get some CORS issues or something similar?

Comment: Very strange. Now it works. I had to put the code into my footer.ejs straight. Normally I have linked a .js file like this `<script type="text/javascript" src="/stylesheets/js/myjsfile.js"></script>` and all the stuff inside is working except the code snippet above so that I had to put it in its own `<script>` tags...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very strange. Now it works. I had to put the code into my footer.ejs straight. Normally I have linked a .js file like this `<script type="text/javascript" src="/stylesheets/js/myjsfile.js"></script>` and all the stuff inside is working except the code snippet above so that I had to put it in its own `<script>` tags... 
Still can't figuring out why it is this way...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    if($("#showP").attr('src') == '' || !$("#showP").attr('src')){
        $("#showP").attr('src', 'https://example.com/standard.png');
    }

});
```

Comment: Please post your complete code including HTML and JS

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have unique id of the image element with `$("#showP").length==1`, your code must work but you can put extra checks as shown in below code

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  if (!$("#showP").attr("src") || $("#showP").attr("src").trim()=="") {
    $("#showP").attr("src", "https://example.com/standard.png");
  }  
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```js
    $(function() {
      if ($("#showP").attr("src") === '') {      
        $("#showP").attr("src", "https://example.com/standard.png");
      }  
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<img id="showP" style="max-width: 80%" class="rounded img-fluid" src="" alt="ASDF">
```